# Undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: java, android

When I use the project as `public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener` and inside that I use `getContentResolver` it show me the error

`The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`

But when I use `public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity` it works for me , but how I can handle it in `public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener`

Code :

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gallery);
        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_edit:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
    //      startActivityForResult(
    //              Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Photo"),
    //              MyConstants.TAKE_PHOTO);
            break;  
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {return;}

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
                    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v)  {  
                              try
                                {
                                InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                                final Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                                }
                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                                }

                          }
                        });

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Reasoning:**

---

> Because **`getContentResolver()`** is the method of the Context Class, not the method of **`View.OnClickListener Interface`**.

And when you are writing this line

```
InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

You are using `this` to call the method from View.OnClickListener Interface, Which is not present in Interface, thats why Android is giving you error.

### [See Context class Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver())  And [View.OnClickListener Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

---

## **Answer:**

---

**Declare a gloabal `Context` Variable.**

```
       // Global Var
       Context context;

       // In onCreate
       context = this;
```

**Change this line to**

```
       InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

**THIS:**

```
       InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Comment: Can you please tell a bit about when we need to use `this` and when we need to use `context`

Answer (score 0):

In this line :

```
InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

"this" refers to the ClickListener you're creating. You need to use the "this" of the enclosing class like that :

```
InputStream is = HomeActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```